# Remove a certain data from the values of a column from dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, nested-lists

1.I have a dataframe with ID containing 'a' and 'b' values as a string :

```
ID                      occ
[['a1'], ['b1']]         3
[['a2'],['a5'],['b2']]   1
[['a3'],['a6'],['b3']]   6
[['a4'], ['b4']]         2
```

I want to remove all the 'a' values from ID column and take the rest
**Expected Result**:

```
ID  occ
b1   3
b2   1
b3   6
b4   2
```

I tried exploding the ID column but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you've a df like this you can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [['a1', 'b1'], ['a2', 'b2'], ['a3', 'b3'], ['a4', 'b4']],'occ': [3, 1, 6, 2]})
df.ID = df.ID.str[1]
```

If ID column is of string type then you can use regex:

```
df.ID = df.ID.str.extract(r'(b\d+)')
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
   ID  occ
0  b1    3
1  b2    1
2  b3    6
3  b4    2
```

Comment: They both are iterating on index value and thus only taking the value on that index. for example at index 1 it is taking only a value and outputting 

a
a
a

Comment: @AnubhavNegi use regex option.

Comment: i tried regex, it is only returning NAN values for all columns

Comment: I have edited the dataframe as exactly as my data now, hope it helps in getting the clearity